# Pandas .shift function yields a "'float' object has no attribute 'shift'", 'occurred at index 0')

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to create a new column in a pandas dataframe using a very complex if statement ***(I have simplified it for the sake of clarity below)***. I keep getting the error: ("'float' object has no attribute 'shift'", 'occurred at index 0').
I have looked around stack/the internet and have not come up with a great answer for my solution. Some answers involve taking the .shift out of a function, however, I need to have it within a function due to the complex nature of the if statement I am writing.

I have attached an image below detailing what I ultimately want the function to do. I believe it explains it better than I could describe it with words.
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Please let me know if you have any questions or if I can clarify anything!

[image: Ultimate end result desired]

Code example

```
df=pd.read_csv(file)

def ubk (df):
    x = df['k_calc'].shift(1)  
    if x <90 :
        return 1
    elif x >90:
        return 2

df['test'] = df.apply(ubk,axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may pass additional parameter to `apply` if you want. In this case you may pass the main `df` and your `ubk` handles/processes it as you want. I don't know exact purpose of your `ubk`, so I just modify `ubk` to accomplish what you describe for column `test`. It seems your logic is not efficient, but you may have your own reason to use it. So, it is up to you.

sample data:

```
In [301]: df
Out[301]:
   lowest_low   k_calc    d_cal
0        9.07  75.0000      NaN
1        9.07  79.7297      NaN
2        9.07  92.5675      NaN
3        9.07  66.2116  78.3772
```

function and call `apply` to create `test` columns with condition: if previous cell of `k_calc < 90` returns 1, `> 90` returns 2 as follows

```
def ubk (s, m_df):
    x = m_df['k_calc'].shift(1)[s.name]  
    if x <90 :
        return 1
    elif x >90:
        return 2

df['test'] = df.apply(ubk, axis=1, args=(df,))

Out[304]:
   lowest_low   k_calc    d_cal  test
0        9.07  75.0000      NaN   NaN
1        9.07  79.7297      NaN   1.0
2        9.07  92.5675      NaN   1.0
3        9.07  66.2116  78.3772   2.0
```

Comment: thank you for the answer! It appears that you have solved my problem. I was wondering if you could elaborate alittle more? Particularly, what does the s.name part do in your solution? I am familiar with the basics of pandas but am still learning the finer points of the library. Also, what is the args part of the .apply function doing?

Comment: @JosiahHulsey: `apply` allows additional parameters through  `args` or `**kwarg` option. `args` requires tuple, so I pass `args=(df,)`. Each row or column got sliced by apply is a series. So,  `s` of `ubk` is a series. `ubk` applies on row, `s.name` is the name of seires got slice by apply. In this case it is the index of current row. Therefore, `m_df['k_calc'].shift(1)[s.name]` means: `on each row, down-shifts column k_calc 1 position and get its cell-value at index = s.name. I.e it effectively is the previous cell-value before the shift`.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just do this:

```
df['test'] = 1+(df['k_calc'].shift(1)>=90).astype(int)
```

The error you get is because you might be misunderstanding what apply does.
When you do `df.apply(ubk,axis = 1)`, pandas will apply ubk to every row in your dataframe. As a result, in your function call, `df` is not your original dataframe but one of its rows. So when you do `x = df['k_calc'].shift(1)`, since `df['k_calc']` is a single entry (a float), pandas complains: he doesn't know any `shift()` method for float.

Comment: For all rows in the dataframe I want to check and see if the previous cell is above or below 90. As mentioned, this is not the final function that I want to use. It is a very complicated if statement. For clarity purposes, I did not include the full if statement in the function because I think it would be more confusing then helpful

Comment: Oh I misunderstood what you were trying to do, my bad. I edited my answer